# Node/Express based server: REPL-like shell possible?

Tags: node.js, express, server, read-eval-print-loop

I have a Node/Express-based server which the frontend will interact with over REST.

However, I also want to be able to interact with this server via a console shell, REPL style.

What is happening though is, when my REPL waits for user input from `stdin` (I'm using the `readline-sync` module), the server cannot receive any REST calls.

I can see how the single-threaded Node is stuck in the foreground waiting for my input from `stdin`, but then how to make an REPL work in an Express-based server?

I tried making the REPL function `async` as shown below, but it made no difference -- probably because, once the REPL starts running the single, foreground thread gets stuck waiting for input:

```
const express = require('express')
const stdin = require('readline-sync')

function readline(prompt = '', echo = true) {
    return stdin.question(prompt, { hideEchoBack: !echo })
}

const app = express()
const port = 3000

app.get('/*', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Hello World!\n')
})

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server listening on port ${port}`)
})

//
;(async () => {
    while (true) {
        let input = readline('Enter something: ')
        console.log(input)
        console.log('You entered: ' + input)
    }
})()
```

Comment: Replace the `readline-sync` module with the built-in `readline` module. Node's own REPL shell is async. Using `readline-sync` will not emulate node's REPL

Comment: Node that `async` does not make something asynchronous. It just makes the function return a `Promise`. And Promises added nothing special to the language - a Promise is just a design pattern (you can implement the Promise class in pure javascript with no modification to the language or interpreter) to handle asynchronous functions.